# Getting syntax error in plotly module file

Tags: python-2.7

Getting error when runnning with apache httpd service but same thing is running fine with flask 5000 port within the virtual env.

[image]

Comment: Can you enter the code it's throwing the error? Are you missing a curly bracket at the end? Are both en a running the exact same version of python?

Comment: user_plot_options= {k: v for k, v in user_plot_options.items()
                                 if  k in default _plot_options}

this is the line of code throwing error from

Comment: the file showing the error is the built-in file of plotly module. the same module with the same file is running fine on Flask :5000 port on server